# sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant authorizing to wrong org

Tags: salesforcedx, jwt

I have set up a Custom app on an enterprise-edition org to deploy source to, and am able to authorize using force:auth:jwt:grant on my dev machine (Windows 10), but the build machine (Windows Server 2016     10.0.14393) consistently connects to a different organization than the one the connected app is defined in.

As a result, the deploy fails.

The server had connected to another org which has since been deleted.  A new organization was created with the same name and user login, and the certificate loaded into a connected app on that organization.  I have confirmed the server is using the new consumer key for the connected app.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Commands on server:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i [certificate] -f server.key -u enterprise@voicestorm.biz -a enterprise
```

response:

> Successfully authorized enterprise@voicestorm.biz with org ID 00D5A00000080jQUAQ

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p .\force-app\main\ -w 10 -u enterprise
```

response:

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - user hasn't approved this consumer
username: enterprise@voicestorm.biz, 
clientId: [different client id], 
loginUrl: https://login.salesforce.com, 
privateKey: server.key 

Try this: 
Verify the OAuth configuration for this org. For JWT:
Ensure the private key is correct and the cert associated with the connected app has not expired.
Ensure the following OAuth scopes are configured [api, refresh_token, offline_access].
Ensure the username is assigned to a profile or perm set associated with the connected app.
Ensure the connected app is configured to pre-authorize admins.
```

Commands on dev machine:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i [certificate] -f server.key -u enterprise@voicestorm.biz -a enterprise
```

response:

> Successfully authorized enterprise@voicestorm.biz with org ID 00D6g000001Y9z2EAC

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p .\force-app\main\ -w 10 -u enterprise
```

response:

> === Deployed Source...

Comment: The username, not the connected app, dictates what org you _attempt_ to connect to. It sounds like your pipeline is configured with an incorrect username somewhere.

Comment: I have copied the command line used in the server to my dev machine (including the username), and the dev machine connects to the correct org, but the server does not.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the commands involved and as much other relevant information as you can.

Comment: So you did verify 00D5A00000080jQUAQ is not the current ORG Id, correct?

Comment: Correct.  00D6g000001Y9z2EAC is the correct Org Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up creating an additional user in the organization with a slightly different name so Salesforce wouldn't tie the user to the old organization.  That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try running the "force:auth:logout" command before the login command.

In your case verify username, consumer key are all setup correctly in the pipeline.